# Cambio dinamico de un grafico de Chart.js dentro de un metodo

Tags: javascript, chart.js, javascript-metodo

Hola tengo un metodo que crea un grafico de Chart.js, el mismo recive como parametro los datos de grafico. Me gustaria que cada vez que llamo al metodo con nueva informacion el grafico cambiara o actualizara.

El Metodo:

```
showInChart(categories, valueOfCategories) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: [...categories],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [...valueOfCategories],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                        'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
              customCanvasBackgroundColor: {
                color: '#fff',
              }
            }
        },
        plugins: [{
            id: 'customCanvasBackgroundColor',
            beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
              const {ctx} = chart;
              ctx.save();
              ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
              ctx.fillStyle = options.color || '#99ffff';
              ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
              ctx.restore();
            }
          }],
    });
}
```

El código así como esta no hace lo que quiero que haga, y no se por donde seguir.

Vi dos publicaciones como esta, pero no me solucionaron nada.

Comment: Hola buenas! Qué dice la documentacion de chart.js sobre actualizar dinámicamente el gráfico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que:

1. Guardar la instancia del gráfico, para esto retornamos el `new Chart` que está en tu función `showInChart` y lo guardamos en una constante `grafico`
2. Luego tienes que fijarte en la misma estructura que tienes dentro del `new Chart`, ahí ya está la información de acceso que tu necesitas. Observa que la estructura es:

- Grafico

  - data (objeto)

    - datasets (array)

      - data (array)

Entonces en `grafico.data.datasets[0].data` está el array con los datos, los cuales podemos modificar, actualizar, borrar y/o agregar

3. finalmente la función  `grafico.update()` se encarga de actualizar

```js
const cat = ["frutas","animales","cosas"];
const dat = [3,1,4];

function update(){
  let datos_fake=[getRandomInt(10),getRandomInt(10),getRandomInt(10)];
  grafico.data.datasets[0].data=datos_fake;
  grafico.update();
}
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function showInChart(categories, valueOfCategories) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
    return new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: categories,
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: valueOfCategories,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                        'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
                    ],
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
              customCanvasBackgroundColor: {
                color: '#fff',
              }
            }
        }
    });
}
const grafico = showInChart(cat,dat);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="update()">Update</button>
<div style="width:300px;height:400px">
   <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```